# ubuntu 12.0 tls hanging at retriving 40 of 90

Tags: 12.04

sir im installing ubuntu 12 on my hp laptop in vmware workstation 8 ,as it comes near retriving it stops at 40 of 90 and stays like that for long ,what to do.
there is internet connection ,tell me a reason

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling "install updates" and "Install extras" checkboxes at the beginning of installation. If "skip" button is active during stall, you can safely press it too. Or may be just try tomorrow - may be your local mirrors have some problems.